# Location Coordinates from an external file

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mapkit

I am creating an application in `Xcode`. The application reads `coordinates` from an external file and list down in a `table view`. When the user clicks in any of the list cell, it opens up a `mapkit` which points to the `coordinate` of according to the cell latitude and longitude.

so far my app can already read the external file, and show the `table view` with the latitude and longitude. It also opens up a view with the map but the problem is I cannot use the coordinates to show the location on the map.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit


class listLoactionTableViewController: UITableViewController {

//array to store the list
var storeLoc = [String:Any]()

var arrayClient = NSMutableArray ()
var readings: [String] = [""]
//add map view

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //get the path where the file is stored
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "gps", ofType: "csv")

    //add file manager to check is the file exist to avoid crash
    let filemgr = FileManager.default

    //grab all content from teh file and store into the string
    //make an array withfrom the string by seperating line

    //iterate the content of the array

    //add the objects fr4om the array for display

    //add all teh field

    //display the amout of line we have title
    if filemgr.fileExists(atPath: path!){
        do {
            let fullText = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

            readings = fullText.components(separatedBy:  "\n") as [String]

            for i in 0..<readings.count{
                let listData = readings[i].components(separatedBy: ";") as [String]

                storeLoc["Latitude"] = "\(listData[0])"
                storeLoc["Longitude"] = "\(listData[1])"
                storeLoc["DateandTime"] = "\(listData[2])"


                arrayClient.add(storeLoc)
                                }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("error: \(error)")
        }
    }

    self.title = "Number of Inputs \(arrayClient.count)"


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return arrayClient.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    let coord = arrayClient[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Latitude:\((coord as AnyObject).object(forKey: "Latitude")!)   Longitude:\((coord as AnyObject).object(forKey: "Longitude")!)"
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Date and Time: \((coord as AnyObject).object(forKey: "DateandTime")!)"
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "oneSegue", sender: arrayClient[indexPath.row])

}
```

it displays the list of all the coordinates correctly. When I click my app opens a segue which has the mapkit

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class showMapViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var showMap: MKMapView!

var selectedName = [String:Any]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

I tried to print the "selectedName.count" and am getting 3 which is correct. I also tried to print according to the index and have also got correct values.

However, I cannot use the latitude and longitude value to show the location on map.

Please help.

Comment: What is the exact problem "However, I cannot use the latitude and longitude value to show the location on map"? Where do you try to "show the location on map"?

Comment: if I print(selectedName) inside the 2nd view, I get 
"["Latitude": "-27.99824106", "DateandTime": "2010-07-07 22:27:31", "Longitude": "153.42096322"]" as an answer. (the values changes according to the index of the list)

I want to use this latitude and longitude to go to the location on the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this example in `showMapViewController`s `viewDidLoad()`:

```
guard let latString =  selectedName["Latitude"] as? String,
    let longString =  selectedName["Longitude"] as? String,
    let latitude = Double(latString),
    let longitude = Double(longString)
    else {
        fatalError("You better handle the error here")
}

let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)        
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

showMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

Comment: Sorry, this solution won't work. I know this is the way to display locations on map. However, the problem here is I am trying to inject the latitude and longitude form an external file. and I am seeking solution on how to inject the latitude and longitude from the external file.

Comment: @Mill3r Sorry. I misunderstood your question than, as you wrote "it displays the list of all the coordinates correctly" I thought you get the coordinates correctly from your file. Added some code to answer.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. 
1. I can read the cvs file and generate a tableview which correctly shows the list. 
2. when I click in a cell it opens up another view to displays the map. 
3. the value that I'm passing through the segue prepare are in the form"["Latitude": "-27.99824106", "DateandTime": "2010-07-07 22:27:31", "Longitude": "153.42096322"]"
4. I am not being able to extract this latitude and longitude value from this string to inject it into the maps CCLocationCoordinates

Comment: I found the solution.. 

I had to use 
let latitude = Double((selectedName["Latitude"] as AnyObject) as! String)!
        
let longitude = Double((selectedName["Longitude"] as AnyObject) as! String)!

Thank you for the help..